# JW Player Sizing Issue in Fancybox

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, jwplayer

I'm using [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to display videos that are hosted through [JW Player](https://www.jwplayer.com/).

It doesn't seem to make a difference if I use the "Single Line Embed Code" that JW Player offers or if I use the iframe option – the video still appears at a max of 100px wide. I can't seem to figure out what's controlling this, and can't see a reason to have to customize fancybox specially for this purpose.

Have anyone else run into this issue?

My HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="#media1" rel="gallery" class="fancybox">01</a>

<div id="media1" class="fancybox-content">
  <script src="//content.jwplatform.com/players/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx.js"></script>
</div>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
.fancybox-content {
  display: none; // This hides any content that should appear within fancyBox
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
}
```

I've setup a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/ericjacksonwood/pen/KNexme) to illustrate the issue I'm having.

Comment: Your codepen works fine in Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was adding 'autoSize:false' option to fancybox. It seems that fancybox was autosizing the box down to the minimum, before the player rendered. The pen is updated and working correctly now.

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox( {
    autoSize: false
});
```